# Virtuemart 3 get customfield params

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

i want get a spesific customfield params on category page(category/default.php),but until now i still can't find a solution,
i tried these method but all not work

method 1

```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('vmcustom', 'mypluginname');
$params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
echo $params->get('param_name','default_value');
```

method 2

```
$plugin = &JPluginHelper::getPlugin('vmcustom', 'mypluginname');
$pluginparams = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
$paramvalue = $pluginparams->get('myparameter');
```

i think maybe these not working,because VM3 version use `<vmconfig>`,don't know is it right,so how can i get a spesific customfield params on category page?

Joomla 3.4.8 / Virtuemart 3.0.12 / Php 5.4

many thanks!